# Forcing cmake to use a specific OpenCV version

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros

My Ubuntu 14.04 has OpenCV 2.4.8 installed by default, and I also have a hand-built OpenCV 2.4.11 that I need for the `cv::fisheye` classes, which I build with `cmake` to produce my executable. The problem is that I am using ROS, which also defaults to 2.4.8, but I need to link with 2.4.11. The hack I have in place is:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
# Needed to force OpenCV 2.4 to link with 2.4.11
#message("Initial value for ${OpenCV_VERSION}: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
if(OpenCV_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.0")
  set(OpenCV_VERSIONED_LIBS "")
  macro(set_opencv_version version)
     foreach( LIB_FILE ${ARGN} )
         set(OpenCV_VERSIONED_LIBS ${OpenCV_VERSIONED_LIBS} :lib${LIB_FILE}.so.${version})
     endforeach()
  endmacro()
  set_opencv_version("2.4.11" ${OpenCV_LIBS})
else()
  set(OpenCV_VERSIONED_LIBS ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif()
#message("Updated value: ${OpenCV_VERSIONED_LIBS}")

target_link_libraries(my_fisheye_application
  ${OpenCV_VERSIONED_LIBS}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  cv_bridge # This by default pulls in OpenCV 2.4.8 libraries
  # ...etc...
)
```

As this script needs to work on different machines and with OpenCV 3.0 as well as 2.4.11, I cannot really make any assumptions about the directories in use. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `The problem is that I am using ROS, which also defaults to 2.4.8, but I need to link with 2.4.11.` - Please, elaborate this more. If nothing else in your package does `find_package(OpenCV)` directly on indirectly, you may use `find_package(OpenCV 2.4.11 REQUIRE)`, so it will find at least *2.4.11* version of OpenCV. If there are other users of OpenCV, and you may not affect on their code, set `OpenCV_DIR` variable as described in the documentation part of [FindOpenCV.cmake](https://github.com/veter-team/cmake-modules/blob/master/windows/FindOpenCV.cmake) module.

Comment: There is the `cv_bridge` module that pulls in `2.4.8` by default - let me add that in.

Comment: By `cv_bridge module that pulls in 2.4.8 by default` I understand that `cv_bridge` module uses OpenCV which it is able to find. As `2.4.8` version is installed on your system, the module takes this version. Am I right? If so, setting `OpenCV_DIR` variable (e.g., as parameter to cmake: `cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=<path-to-opencv-2.4.11>` should force both `cv_bridge` and your module to use OpenCV 2.4.11.

Comment: **find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)** has a version parameter. Did you tried that? See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to force CMake (the FindOpenCV module) to search for an OpenCV library different from the package/system installed one,
you need to set `OpenCV_ROOT_DIR` variable to the base directory of OpenCV tree to use.

Also, because you want at least a specific minimum version of the OpenCV library, it's better to state it in the find_package() function, as the following:

```
find_package(OpenCV 2.4.11 REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Just to warn than in Cmake version **13.18** the variable name to set the path to is `OpenCV_ROOT` without `_DIR` suffix. IE: `set(OpenCV_ROOT "/absolute/path/to/your/opencv/root/directory")`